# Problems when obtaining an id, sent by a form

Tags: django

Good evening, I am trying to get the id of my model Note that is sent by means of a form, but when I put form.id it tells me that id is not defined, try to get it through the user session but it says that it was not found.

```
def add_book(request):
    template_name = 'books/create_note.html'
    book = get_or_create_book(request)
    form = NoteForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        note = Note.objects.get(pk=form.pk)
        book.notes.add(note)
        form.save()
        return redirect('books:book')
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form,
    })
```

and this is the form

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = (
            'title', 'nota'
        )
        labels = {
            'title': 'Titulo',
            'nota': 'Nota',
        }
```

try creating an instance of my Note model but when it comes time to create it tells me it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Django, but I had similar problems that frustrate me. not sure if I have the hang of it yet, but  I think what might be happening is that when you first go to the page there is a GET request, so your if statement misses it. It then it reaches the last line and goes to template_name without the form being assigned so the form never gets a Post requests. In the terminal you can see the POST and GET requests. I ended up also printing out request.method a lot before and after if statements just to help trace what was going on.

```
else:
    form=NoteForm()
```

Then your return render(request,....
making sure it goes back to the correct html page.

The thing that worked for me eventually was something like

def Search_Page(request):

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form = Search_Page_Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        do some stuff and save the change to the model


        return(redirect('mainapp:Evaluate_Page'))
else:
    form=Search_Page_Form()
return render(request, 'mainapp/Search_Page.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: in my case the form if it is sent, what I want is to know if there is some way to get the id of what I send

Comment: I think If there is something in the form you should be able to show it in the template  using {{ form.id }}, and see the id. If you loop it you should see all the ids in the form.   I am not sure if you can print out all the parts of the post request, I know you can test to see if something is in the POST request like    if 'image_on' in request.POST:

Comment: If I can paint it, what I want is to know if I can get all the information I send and get its id, because I need it, for my query note = Note.objects.get (pk = form.pk)